# Не срабатывает скрипт onLoad

Tags: javascript

Не знаю как правильно объяснить в общем вот код https://jsfiddle.net/l2banners/n50oeyfv/3/

```
 window.onload = function() {
     var forma = document.forma,
         input = forma.input,
         i = input.length,
         array = {
             value1 : 'Значение 1',
             value2 : 'Значение 2',
             value3 : 'Значение 3',
             value4 : 'Значение 4'
         };

     while(i--) {
         input[i].onchange = function(i) {
             return function() {
                 forma.text.value = array[this.value];
                 document.getElementById('Image').src =
                     array[this.value].match(/src="([^"]+)"/)[1];
             };
         }(i);
     }
 };

 function checkDisableButton() {
     checkReadRulles = document.getElementById('checkReadRulles');
     submiteButton = document.getElementById('submiteButton');

     if (checkReadRulles.checked) {
         submiteButton.disabled = "";
     } else {
         submiteButton.disabled = "disabled";
     }
 }
```

Проблема в том что в обычном html все работает, как только закидываю на сайт, переключатели перестают срабатывать. Заметил что если в этом редакторе на который я дал ссылку поставить Load type - onLoad  то тоже не работает, а если поставить onDomreader то все работает, я не очень понимаю что это и почему не срабатывает на сайте, хотя на html все работает. Подскажите что делать или посоветуйте похожее решение.

Comment: 1. Для чего `checkDisableButton()`? 2. Вот такие `.onload =`, `.onchange = ` меняйте на `addEventListener()` хотя бы; 3. Чем по вашему отличается "обычный html" от "закинутого на сайт"? 4. Что именно должно работать и что именно не работает?

Comment: При нажатии на разные чекбоксы меняется содержимое текстериа, при включении Load type - onDomreader  оно работает как надо, вот тоже самое с onDomreader   https://jsfiddle.net/l2banners/n50oeyfv/4/

Comment: 3. в том то и дело я вообще не представляю чем оно отличается, должно вроде как работать...

Comment: 1.2. я не разбираюсь в js

Comment: А этот код вы где взяли?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
// Слушаем событие загрузки страницы, чтобы нужные нам элементы уже
// появились в DOM
    var forma = document.forms['forma'],
        input = forma.elements,
        i = input.length,
        values = {
            value1: 'Значение 1',
            value2: 'Значение 2',
            value3: 'Значение 3',
            value4: 'Значение 4'
        },
        ta = forma.elements['text'];
    while (i--) {
        if (input[i] == ta) continue;
        // На <textarea> событие вешать не нужно
        input[i].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            // На каждую радиокнопку вешаем обработчик
            ta.value = values[e.target.value];
            // Меняем содержимое <textarea> на значение, которое
            // соответствует нажатой радио кнопке
            document.getElementById('Image').src =
                values[e.target.value].match(/src="([^"]+)"/)[1];
            // Для чего это в вашем коде - непонятно. Возможно что
            // вообще не нужно
        });
    }
});
```

Все это будет работать в современных браузерах. Если требуется поддержка старых IE, скрипт придется доработать.

PS. А JavaScript поучите. Пригодится, поскольку такие вопросы у вас появились.

Comment: То же самое в режимме onLoad не работает https://jsfiddle.net/l2banners/n50oeyfv/5/

Comment: @l2banners И не должно. Должно работать на вашем сайте. Если вы ставите в jsfiddle "способ запуска" onLoad - это означает, что написанное в окне JavaScript должно запускаться по событию `window.onload` а в указанном мной скрипте ставится обработчик этого события (которое два раза не происходит). Если хотите проверить на jsfiddle укажите метод запуска `<head>` или `<body>`

Comment: На сайте, точно так же не запускается... Движек DLE 10.6 засунул скрипт в addnews и нечего не происходит, не знаю в чем проблема...

Comment: В варианте запуска в `<head>` или `<body>` например https://jsfiddle.net/n50oeyfv/6/ все работает, поэтому решение корректное. Почему не работает в DLE нужно разбираться более глубоко с изучением сообщений в консоли и сформированного кода страницы. У меня о DLE очень неприятное впечатление

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, проще будет табами сделать.